# hide and show function isn't working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i wants to apply a condition that if edit button is clicked then it show or hide another portion, i have applied the condition to do it but its not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edit-invited-btn").click(function() {
    $(".edit-invited2").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4" id="edit-invited2">
  <select id="subjects" name="subjects" class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Select Teacher" style="width: 100%;" multiple>
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button class="pull-right" id="edit-invited-btn">Edit</button>
```

Comment: where is the element `.edit-invited`

Comment: You have an id called `edit-invited2`. So, change it to: `$("#edit-invited2").toggle()`?

Comment: $("#edit-invited2").toggle(); but no hiding its continuous showing

Comment: We both edited at the same time, no offense!

Comment: but not in my project

Comment: You have changed to `$(".edit-invited2").toggle()` It should be `$("#edit-invited2").toggle()`. **#** for Id selector

Comment: @alpha dev : Please check click event may be bind two times... Add alert('Test'); before click event selector

Comment: @thnx adiga......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".edit-invited2")` should be `$("#edit-invited2")`. In `html`, `edit-invited2` is an `id` and not class.

```js
$("#edit-invited-btn").click(function() {
  $("#edit-invited2").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4" id="edit-invited2">
  <select id="subjects" name="subjects" class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Select Teacher" style="width: 100%;" multiple>
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button class="pull-right" id="edit-invited-btn">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".edit-invited").toggle();`

There is no class named edit-invited in your code check once

If you want to toggle `id="edit-invited"` than replace

`$(".edit-invited").toggle();`

**To**

`$("#edit-invited").toggle();`

Comment: $(".edit-invited2").toggle();

Comment: but still same result no hiding